# Is it possible to get consistent address_components data from the geocoder API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I'm using this:
geocoder.geocode( geoRequest, function(results, status) {
...
...
}

The problem is that the data returned from the geocoder seems to be inconsistent. It is probably worth mentioning that when I load the js file for the maps API before calling the geocoder, I specify the language, (and that I also specify the country (e.g.: AU for australia) in the variable geoRequest in the geocoder.geocode call).

To make it simpler for others to see what I try to understand we can just use this URL:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:AU&language=en&address=darwin

The interesting parts in the result is that this request returnes these address_components long_name:

Australia

Northern Territory (short_name=NT)

Darwin

If I include "briggs street" in the search so I get this url:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:AU&language=en&address=briggs+street,darwin

then I get these address_components long_name:

Australia

Northern Territory (short_name=NT)

Darwin Municipality

Darwin City

Briggs Street

**My questions:**

Why is "Darwin" not returned in the second example where I search for "briggs street,darwin"? In this case the text is:

Darwin Municipality

Darwin City

Is it possible to inform the geocoder API that I want consistent hierarcical results returned, both with and without specifying e.g. a road?

The reason I'm asking is that I want to gather som statistical information, based on user specified locations, either by entering a name of a city, or a street. I hope to be able to use the returned component_addresses to build at database with other information from the client (user).

But the statistics reports will not be very consistent if e.g. one want to see some statistics for Darwin (those registered by users only entering "darwin"), since the data entered by a user entering "briggs street,darwin" will not get the data stored below the location "Darwin" (as for the first user) - since "Darwin" is different from "Darwin City" and "Darwin Minicipality".

**Similar inconsistency can be observed searching for "fulton street,brooklyn" and "brooklyn"**

This search for brooklyn:
?components=country:US&address=brooklyn

returns:

USA

New York (short_name=NY)

Kings County

New York

Brooklyn

But... this search for "fulton+street,brooklyn":
?components=country:US&address=fulton+street,brooklyn

returns:

USA

New York (short_name=NY)

Kings County

Brooklyn

Fulton Street

Why is there no "New York" between "Kings County" and "Brooklyn" in the last result above? Again... there seem to bee some inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example, now for Denmark:

A search for odense:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:DK&language=en&address=odense

gives me this result:

Denmark

Region Syddanmark (administrative_area_level_1)

[...]

If I search for the street ryttergade in odense, like this: 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:DK&language=en&address=ryttergade,odense

then the region "Region Syddanmark" (administrative_area_level_1) is not in the resultset. Why is it so?

Is there a way to inform the geocoder that I do want administrative_area_level_1 returned in resultsets where e.g. street name is included?

Comment: Please add examples by editing your question rather than answering it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get them by reverse geocoding latlngs, but not always by geocoding street-level addresses.

**Darwin**

[address=Darwin](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:AU&language=en&address=darwin) returns a colloquial city, which is different from the "Darwin City" you get [address=briggs+street,darwin](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:AU&language=en&address=briggs%20street,darwin). Colloquial cities are marked with `"types": ["colloquial_area", "locality", "political"]` instead of `"types" : ["locality", "political"]`

The (non colloquial) of "Darwin City" is contained by the "Darwin Municipality", while the colloquial city of "Darwin" is not. The latter is only contained by the next (greater) political division, "Northern Territory", which also contains the "Darwin Municipality". This explains the components you see.

**Brooklyn**

Brooklyn and a few other parts of New York City are a bit special. There, the name of the city (New York) is not relevant for postal addresses. This is why street-level addresses are not supposed to have the locality, and so is `address_components`

**Odense**

Same as in Brooklyn, except that this seems to be the case in the entire country: the `administrative_area_level_1` component doesn't show up because it's not relevant for street-level addresses.